# Why the content of a pointer to char can be a string but I can't scanf a pointer to char without reserving memory?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, scanf, c-strings

Why is the first option OK but the second option should use dynamic memory and the first doesn't?

```
//first option
char *p = "hello";
//second option
char *p;
scanf("%s",p);
//and introduce hello on the terminal
```

Comment: Because in the first case the compiler allocates space for the string, and in the second case it doesn't. It has no way of knowing how many characters the user will type at the terminal, so doesn't know how much space to allocate. Though even if you used `scanf("%5s",p);`, it still wouldn't allocate it for you. This is just how C (and the `scanf` funtion) works. Note that if you use `scanf("%ms",&p);` memory WILL be allocated... which should later be `free`ed. Read the man-page for `scanf`.

Comment: and what happens if instead of scanf it would be sscanf("hello","%s",p); It would work as p = "hello" ?

Comment: The first option is wrong? The compiler does not give me any warning or error when I compile it..

Comment: @eltramas: I believe that I misunderstood your question. The first option is wrong, if you do `scanf("%s",p);` after the line `char *p = "hello";` However, I am not sure if that is what you intend. The `scanf("%s",p);` probably only belongs to the second option, not the first option. I have therefore deleted my first comment.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, the first option is only char *p = "hello"; and the second option the scanf, they are in seperated programs, not in the same..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `p` in this declaration

```
//first option
char *p = "hello";
```

points to the first character of the string literal "hello" that is stored in memory as a character array of the type `char[6]`.

You can imagine it the following way

```
char string_literal[] = "hello";
char *p = string_literal;
```

Only pay attention to that you may not change a string literal pointed to by a pointer. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. For example you may not write

```
char *p = "hello";
p[0] = 'H';
```

In this code snippet

```
//second option
char *p;
scanf("%s",p);
```

the pointer `p` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value. So the call of scanf invokes undefined behavior.

At least you could write for example

```
char s[6];
char *p = s;

scanf( "%s", p ); // or scanf( "%5s", p );
```

to enter the string `"hello"`;

Or if to use sscanf referred in your comment to the question you could write

```
char s[6];
char *p = s;

sscanf( "hello", "%s", p );
```

Comment: so for this reason sscanf should work because the program will know the characters isn it?

Comment: @eltramas I have not understood what you mean

Comment: @eltramas See my appended answer.

Comment: char *p = s;

sscanf( "hello", "%s", p );  //why it could not be just like this if the compiler now knows how many bytes has to reserve? I mean now it knows that it must reserve 5 bytes..

Comment: @eltramas The compiler reserves nothing. It is you who has to reserve enough bytes to copy the string in the reserved memory.

Comment: yes, but the reason the compiler reserves memory in p = "hello" is because it knows the strlen of "hello", so in the case of sscanf also knows the strlen of the string, so if it works for p = "hello" it should ork also for sscanf..

Comment: @eltramas The compiler reserved the memory for the string literal "hello". But it does not allocate memory that will be pointed to by the pointer p. It is your task to initialize the pointer p with the address of a reserved memory (character array) where the string literal will be copied.

Comment: @Vald from Moscow I am trying to understand what you wrote, could you write it on code what is exactly the program making when I make p = "hello"? Thanks

Comment: @eltramas See my updated answer.

Comment: I would be inclined to add a little blurb about how `"%s"` is a really bad idea with the `*scanf` family of functions. Given an input array of size `6` then `"%5s"` makes it good.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first case the compiler allocates (usually) memory for the string in "static" memory.  So p is pointing to storage that contains the string constant.

The second case, p is uninitialized, and points to nothing. So you have to allocate memory for it.  The alternative to using heap-based allocation is to define like

```
char p[100];
scanf("%100s",p);
```

you are still allocating memory in this case, but on the stack.  Either way, C strings (and pointers) need some valid memory area to point to, whether it is on the stack, heap, or static.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want in the second case, you would need to do it like this:

```
char *p;

printf("Enter a word: ");
scanf("%ms",&p);
printf("User entered '%s'\n",p);
free(p);
```

The `m` option to `%s` (in `scanf`) tells `scanf` to allocate whatever memory is needed for the string. Read the `scanf` man-page for more details.

Comment: wow, this is really interesting, could you make the large method? I think it was something like p = (char*)malloc(strlen(word)+1) or something like that..

Comment: @char*argv[] There is no such a length modifier in the C Standard for scanf.

Comment: @eltramas I don't know what you mean by "the large method"; but using `%ms` is the same as `p = malloc(strlen(word) + 1)`, except that you don't need to know what `word` is (or how long it is) in advance.